# jqgrid viewrecords update after search

Tags: php, jqgrid, pagination

I have a jqgrid showing 117 total records in 50 rows per page (rowNum set to 50).
When I look at the bottom pager it reports correctly "View 1-50 of 117" for the first page, "View 51-100 of 117" for the second, and so on.

If I perform a search (single search) returning, for example, 63 total records matching the filters, I expect to read at the bottom of the first page something like "View 1-50 of 63" (and in the jqGrid examples this is what happen). 
In my case, even if the records in the grid are 63 after the search operation, the bottom pager always shows "View 1-50 of 117", but obviously there are only 50 records in the first page and 13 in the second.

I looked at the documentation and examples, and it seems that what I'm trying to achieve would be the default behaviour... is it a bug? I'm using jqGrid 4.2.0

Thanks

Comment: Which `datatype` you use? Do you use `loadonce: true` or get the data (or filter the data) from the server?

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I use json datatype and getting/filtering data from the server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `datatype: 'json'` and not use the option `loadonce: true` additionally then you have implemented the filtering of data on the server side. If `_search` parameter from the server request has `true` then the server should produce the response based on the filter parameter. In the case you should place in the `records` part of the JSON response not the total number of *filtered* records. I suppose that you place always just the total number of non-filtered records.

Comment: Yes, you're right. On the serverside script I use "records" with the result of a select count, and it's always 117 (the total). Is there a way to solve the problem? I have to work on the server side or is it possible to solve in some other way?

Comment: OK, solved very easily by adding the where clause to the postgres query on the server side php script. Thanks for your suggestion Oleg, it helped me to understand the issue!